# merge linestrings with group_by common attribute in PostgreSQL/Postgis

Tags: postgis, postgresql-9.6

I am attempting to combine a series of linestring geometries with a matching attribute (road_name_search and road_id), and then join merged linestring back to the road_id attribute from the following sample data

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f52d21 (please note - if you copy this to a database, you will need to change the type of the shape column to geometry(MultiLineString,2193)) ... is there a PostGIS version of SQL fiddle?)

I have tried using the code below which works well to combine the road names:

```
SELECT 
MAX (road_id),
road_name_search
FROM a_road_test 
GROUP BY road_name_search
```

This appears to work as expected with the following results:

```
max         road_name_search
3033986     Kennedy Road (Onekawa)
3033986     Kennedy Road (Greenmeadows)
3033986     Kennedy Road (Marewa)
1808281     Kennedy Road (Pyes Pa)
3033986     Kennedy Road (Pirimai)
```

Next, I tried to include the geometry strings, so I end up with everything I need...When I extend the query to include clustering of the geometry string like so

```
SELECT 
MAX (road_id),
road_name_search,
unnest(ST_ClusterIntersecting(shape))
FROM a_road_test 
GROUP BY road_name_search
```

Then I end up with duplicated road_name_search_fields, i.e. more than one occurrence of each, eg.

```
1808281 Kennedy Road (Pyes Pa)      geoma
3033986 Kennedy Road (Pirimai)      geomb
3033986 Kennedy Road (Pirimai)      geomc
3033986 Kennedy Road (Onekawa)      geomd
3033986 Kennedy Road (Greenmeadows) geome
3033986 Kennedy Road (Greenmeadows) geomf
3033986 Kennedy Road (Marewa)       geomg
3033986 Kennedy Road (Marewa)       geomh
```

Next approach, exclude the unnest function...
    SELECT 
    MAX (road_id),
    road_name_search,
    ST_ClusterIntersecting(shape)
    FROM a_road_test 
    GROUP BY road_name_search

Now I end up with...

```
1808281 Kennedy Road (Pyes Pa)  [geoma]
3033986 Kennedy Road (Pirimai)  [geomb, geomc]
3033986 Kennedy Road (Onekawa)  [geomd]
3033986 Kennedy Road (Greenmeadows) [geome, geomf]
3033986 Kennedy Road (Marewa)   [geomg, geomh]
```

Just can't quite figure out how to...

```
1808281 Kennedy Road (Pyes Pa)      geoma
3033986 Kennedy Road (Pirimai)      geombc
3033986 Kennedy Road (Onekawa)      geomd
3033986 Kennedy Road (Greenmeadows) geomef
3033986 Kennedy Road (Marewa)       geomgh
```

Thanks for looking :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Consider also sharing the result of this query of yours. Another thing that will significantly improve your chances to get an answer is to provide a create table statement with some sample data, preferably in a sqlfiddle ;-) good luck!

Comment: Thanks Jim Jones, I have made the changes you suggested - hopefully this helps it to be more useful for others. Thanks, Nick

Comment: you mean `SELECT MAX(road_id), road_name_search, ST_Union(shape) FROM a_road_test GROUP BY road_name_search`?

Comment: @ecwz thankyou - I don't have access to the database for 2 weeks while on leave but will test when I get back and confirm. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A very simple answer as identified by @ewcz

```
SELECT MAX(road_id), 
road_name_search, 
ST_Union(shape) 
FROM a_road_test 
GROUP BY road_name_search
```